Running a trading algorithm- On-premises vs Cloud
I am seeking insights from traders who have implemented algorithmic trading programs on the cloud or at their local workstations. My goal is to determine the most efficient, cost-effective, and scalable option that meets my performance and security requirements.
Project Overview:
I am looking to implement a medium frequency trading system that trades in capital markets. My initial setup executes orders per 10 seconds, but I will upscale it to 1 millisecond in due course. I have reservations about the scalability of my local machine to handle varying loads. Also, I came across multiple resources that suggest cloud solutions are more reliable. I am also skeptical about redundancy and failover mechanisms on the cloud. Is my data secure?
Given my strategy executes orders in a time-sensitive interval, latency and bandwidth are my utmost priority. Also, cloud solutions are managed services so I can better focus on monitoring the system, rather than doing maintenance. Any suggestions about system configurations and networking protocols are most welcome.

This is also posted on Hardware Recommendations.  https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18985/running-a-trading-algorithm-on-premise-vs-cloud

I know. Utilizing multiple platforms to gain various perspectives.
